# Using a fresh initial migration to squash migrations

Tags: python, django, migration, squash

I have an app with 35 migrations which take a while to run (for instance before tests), so I would like to squash them.

The `squashmigrations` command reduces the operations from 99 to 88, but it is still far from optimal. This is probably due to the fact that I have multiple `RunPython` operations preventing Django from optimizing other operations. All these `RunPython` operations are useless in the squashed migration because the database is empty. In Django 1.10 the `elidable` parameter will allow to skip them in this case, but still, a lot of clutter remains.

What I had in mind for the squashed migration was closer to the initial migrations Django generates, hence my question:

Is it advisable to use a fresh initial migration as a squashed version of a long list of migrations? How would you do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have any important data in your test or production databases your can use fresh initial migration and it will be appropriate solution.

I've used this trick a lot of times and it works for me.

A few thoughts:

- sometimes, first you need to create migrations for one of your local application and then for all the others;
- to be sure that all be ok you can commit your migrations and backup you db before you run `./migrate` with empty db.

**NOTE:** to speed up your tests you can try to run in memory tests and/or run tests with sqlite if its possible.

Comment: Thanks! How do you generate the initial migration though? Do you move away all the current migrations to a different folder?

Comment: Usually I just remove folders 'migrations' under each of my local apps. Generally I use PostreSQL. so in simplest case I run this: `dropdb dbname && createdb dbname && rm -rf some_application/migrations && python manage.py migrate`